# Scroll to zoom on a mac with a non-mac usb mouse

Tags: mouse, zoom

Moving over to a mac from windows and one feature I really enjoyed was being able to map my scroll up and scroll down keys and (+) and (-) respectively.

Then, while in a web browser or picture preview I could hold ctrl and scroll up and down to zoom in and out.

I have been having trouble implementing this for my mac. I tried the better touch tool but can't seem to make it work with that.

I also tried System Preferences->Accessibility->Zoom to change the settings there but it does not increase the size of whatever I am viewing, it just actually zooms in the entire computer screen (which is an unwanted effect).

Answer (score 1):

Some programs may allow you to use cmd+scroll to zoom in or out (it works in Firefox at least)

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of zoom. The one you most likely ran into was the full-screen-zoom, and you're correct, it's not what you're looking for. The other one is per-application zoom. The short answer is that an application must support using scroll to zoom, there is no system setting for this. The pinch to zoom is included as a system setting as convenience to the user.